# Is there any way to work with JdbcTemplate and Query/Criteria Fluent API

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-jdbc, spring-data-r2dbc

R2dbcEntityTemplate has a method called **[select](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/r2dbc/docs/1.1.x/api/)** that allows me to use `org.springframework.data.relational.core.query.Query` to build my query statement using a Fluent API. I'm looking for a way to use this Fluent API on spring-data-jdbc in a non reactive project. I din't find any method in `JdbcTemplate` that I can pass a Query or CriteriaDefinition as parameter.

This is an example using R2dbcEntityTemplate:

```
r2dbcTemplate.select(OrderItem.class)
    .matching(query(where("order_id").is(orderId)))
    .all();
```

Any thoughts on how to use this with JdbcTemplate?

Comment: `JdbcTemplate` doesn't have similar functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Data JDBC doesn't have such an API.

You might want to look into [Querydsl](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/tree/master/querydsl-sql) or [jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/).